# Is there any reason for including the tag name with a class or ID selector in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm wondering if there is any difference between `div.class` and `.class` as CSS selectors if there is only one tag (the DIV) with that attribute.  Same thing for IDs: `div#ID` and `#ID`.

Any idea what, if anything, is the difference?  For me, I use the class or ID in these situations; but only because it's quicker to type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. They are more specific, so long ones will override the shorter version if they conflict. `div.foo` will have a specificity of 11 while `.foo` has a specificity of 10.
2. Since they are more specific, you know exactly which nodename the class applies to instead of being a universal rule for all node names, this can help if you have a huge application with tons of elements that all have the same class names, it can lessen the time for you to find the element in the source/text editor.

Answer (score 1):

There is only a VERY SLIGHT difference in specificity.

```
p#id is (0,1,0,1)
```

and

```
#id is (0,1,0,0)
```

in otherwords, the tag itself doesn't hold very much specificity at all compared to an ID, and relying on that kind of tiny specifity to overrule things is almost never needed in my experience.

More importantly, NOT tag-qualifiying selectors is more efficient for the browser to render.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/   and    http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to just a class or id, as you do, means that your CSS will still apply if the HTML tag is changed to a different tag.

Most of the time, this is probably exactly what you want — classes are there to allow you to add a custom layer of meaning on top of HTML.

In general, your selectors should be the minimum required to express your meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Usually those longer selectors come in handy once the majority of the CSS has already been done. Sometimes you want to tweak a little thing here and there - say - differenciate between `p.error` and `div.error` for example. So instead of adding another class - and thus having to touch the HTML - you can simply add an element name to your selector instead, for more fine grained control.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no difference if you only have DIV tags of the specific class or ID.