# Selectors in CSS & jQuery: just the class/id, or the tag as well?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Working with class/id selectors in CSS and in jQuery, I often see two distinct approaches:

**1. Just the class or id:**

**CSS:**

```
.foo{}

#bar{}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".foo")

$("#bar")
```

**2. The class or id with its tag:**

**CSS:**

```
div.foo{}

div#bar{}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("div.foo")

$("div#bar")
```

---

My question is: Barring the use of the tag to further refine the selector, is there anything wrong with placing the tag with the class/id? Which is proper syntax?

I've heard some that say that unless the tag is needed for specificity, it is dead wrong to place it. While others say it makes no difference, and in fact prefer it as it provides further information concerning the selector.

What do you think?

Comment: Adding the tag will hit performance and become slower, avoid it if you don't need it. Try to follow a common pattern though.

Comment: @Nico - Thanks! Great information. Much appreciated.

Comment: Not quite sure why my question was voted down. Was it not legitimate?

Comment: @Nico - actually, I believe it's the opposite. Specificity increases performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any reason for including the tag name with a class or ID selector in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089004/is-there-any-reason-for-including-the-tag-name-with-a-class-or-id-selector-in-css)

Comment: @stefmikhail it's a valid question with interesting answers. +1'ed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the tag included

`$("div.foo")` or `div.foo{}`

you are giving the browser a hand, telling it not to search every element with a certain class or ID.  Instead, in the examples above, it would just search `div`s.

Although the performance may be negligible on a single element or a small page, it could add up if you are talking about a document with thousands of tags and several different css or jQuery calls.

**Distinguishing between two elements**

In some cases you may need it, too, to distinguish between two elements with the same class.

**For Specificity**

Plus, I think that you should include the elements when possible, as a way to make your CSS (and jQuery) as specific as possible... keeping the surprises to a minimum!

**Better for shared code/troubleshooting/updating**

It is also much easier to find/change/edit rules when the element is included in the rule.

**EDIT**

To respond to @stefmikhail's comment about @YoTsumi's benchmark test, here is the difference:

Searching for a unique ID will always be the fastest thing, as there should only be one ID on a page and the engine needs to look for it and it alone.  However, as @BoltClock mentioned, there is more to this question than performance.

Comment: So are you essentially saying that even if the element type selector is not needed for specificity, it should be used to increase performance if, say, only the class `foo` belongs to a `div`?

Comment: I am just going to upvote this answer instead of wasting my rep downvoting every other answer that **focuses solely on performance** without any concern for such matters as the fact that `div.foo` and `.foo` **do not select exactly the same set of elements**, especially when no such assumption was made about the HTML in the question, and when the question didn't mention performance in the first place.

Comment: If selectors are your bottleneck when it comes to rendering styles, you have a much bigger problem to solve.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock.  Agreed...to both comments!

Comment: @BoltClock - I specifically stated the following, ***"Barring the use of the tag to further refine the selector"*** to make the question about speed and syntax when the tag was *not* needed to further specify the selected element.

Comment: @stefmikhail to your first comment, yes.  Basically the browser doesn't have to waste its time looking at everything element for a class match.  It can focus on the `div`s

Comment: @Jason Gennaro - So what would you say about YoTsumi's answer, and his benchmark?

Answer (score 5):

I've just write a benchmark to compare with and without the tag.

http://jsperf.com/id-class-and-tag

If you expect best performances : **don't add the tag !**

Comment: Thanks for jspref coulden't find it in my bookmarks when I was writing my answer ;)

Comment: Very interesting. Looks like I'm getting conflicting answers from different people. Yours is what I have always believed; That adding the tag slows down the query.

Comment: Also it makes sense: the underlaying selector just checks all the elements, if it has the right id it doesn't need to check anymore, since id's are unique. if you also include the tag in the selector, it needs to check if the found match also has the correct tag.

Comment: @YoTsumi - Also, look at the speed difference between Chrome and Firefox, especially on `id` selectors. I never knew `id` selectors were so much faster than `class` selectors. Why is it then that jQuery has `.addClass` but for `id` you have to add an attribute? Or is this unrelated and has to do with sizzle?

Comment: @stefmikhail it depends on what browsers you want to support to be fast to find elements <IE8 finds div.class faster then .class because it has to look on all DOM elements, by filtering the `document.getElementsByTagname` it has allot less to look into.   and for the `#id` question there is nothing as fast as `document.getElementById` because as soon as you found one element with that ID it has the DOM element you looked after.

Comment: @voigtan - that's interesting because, while I always use `id` instead of `class` when there is only one element to be selected, I remember reading a document where it encouraged people to just forget about `id`s all together, and use only `class`. I think it had to do with ease if you ever needed, in the future, to use that selector on more than one element. Obviously there are many opinions when it comes to selectors.

Comment: Im just talking about the javascript part about finding elements now (older browsers), classes is the better way to style elements. The positive part about javascript and IDs is that it doesnt "forgive" users that is using IDs as classes on their homepages witch I like :) you should use the correct attribute on the right elements.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's more performant for the selector engine of either (CSS or jQuery) to be as specific as possible (i.e., include the tag) - but you may never notice the difference. Here's a quote from jQuery creator John Resig discussing the selectors people use in their jQuery code:

> For example, “.class” is far more popular than “tag.class” even though the second one is much more performant. What’s especially important about this is that the degree of performance hit isn’t that much of an issue. For example, the difference between 4ms and 30ms is virtually imperceptible. ([Source](http://ejohn.org/blog/selectors-that-people-actually-use/))

Comment: Excellent answer! This is what I was looking for. Curious, when you say 'performant', what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

in jquery an plain ID is the fastest way you can find an element on a document, the next one (now I say fastest with all versions of browsers). Because jquery uses `document.getElementById` to find the DOM element. The Class on the other hand can be tricky, sizzle will run on it, and I actually think div.foo is faster then .foo because with a collection of the elements is allot lower then looking on all elements in the DOM. modern browsers has query selectors that will be faster then using the element name (note that I haven't done tests on this). Older browsers will find div.class faster then .class but in modern browsers you should get the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting this from Wiley's Smashing CSS book "

> It’s hard to say three times quickly and can be even harder to thoroughly grasp, but it’s the key
>   to understanding how CSS rules interact with each other.
>   Specificity is a numeric representation of the “specific-ness” of a selector. There are three
>   things that are used to determine a selector’s specifi city:

1. Every element descriptor contributes 0,0,0,1.
2. Every class, pseudo-class, or attribute descriptor contributes 0,0,1,0.
3. Every ID descriptor contributes 0,1,0,0.
   Don’t freak out (yet)! Take a look at a few examples fi rst.
   div ul ul li 0,0,0,4 Four element descriptors
   div.aside ul li 0,0,1,3 One class descriptor, three element descriptors
   a:hover 0,0,1,1 One pseudo-class descriptor, one element descriptor
   div.navlinks
   a:hover
   0,0,2,2 One pseudo-class descriptor, one class descriptor, two element
   descriptors
   :hash:title em 0,1,0,1 One ID descriptor, one element descriptor
   h1:hash:title em 0,1,0,2 One ID descriptor, two element descriptors
   Hopefully, this begins to give you an idea of how specifi city values are built up. Now, why the
   commas? Because each “level” of specifi city value stands on its own, so to speak. Th us, a
   selector with a single class descriptor has more specifi city than a selector with 13 element
   descriptors."
   So singnificance of overriding styles is presented with adding the tag names, as far as jQuery is concerned w.r.t classes u could always use selectors preceding them as some of the class names like "active" can apply to multiple (inline and block level ) elements leading to undesired effects. Hope this helped in some way...Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I hop between the two like a itchy owl..

Sometimes it's nice to see the tag name to remind you (and your) co-workers what it is your actually working with and what kind of behaviour you can expect.

I think it's fine to use either.

Go with what feel most natural (doesn't make your eyes hurt)

Comment: I appreciate your honesty. This is also where I stand at the moment... although I feel we both would be chastised for it by certain commenters on this thread... ;)